# Objective-C, retaining a variable after NSLog-output

Tags: objective-c, properties, nsstring, nslog, weak-references

I would like to know how weak property work in Objective-C.
In this example the value of the weak property "myString" in "myClass" is kept only when I print it with NSLog. Why is that?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <stdio.h>

@interface myClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, weak)NSString *myString;
- (void)readString;
@end

@implementation myClass
@synthesize myString;
- (void)readString
{
    const int MAXBUFFER = 80;
    char buffer[MAXBUFFER+1];
    NSLog(@"Input string:");
    fgets(buffer, MAXBUFFER, stdin);
    NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buffer];
    myString = tempString;
    NSLog(@"myString: %@", myString);  // Why does this line make all the difference?
}
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        myClass *myInstance = [[myClass alloc] init];
        [myInstance readString];
        NSLog(@"myInstance.myString: %@", myInstance.myString);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the NSLog-line in the readString-method is commented out myInstance.myString becomes "(null)".  Why??

Answer (score 1):

From Apple:

> weak Specifies that there is a weak (non-owning) relationship to the
>   destination object. If the destination object is deallocated, the
>   property value is automatically set to nil.

So Basically when arc insert code into [readString], he does:

```
NSString *tempString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:buffer];
    myString = tempString;
// + arc [tempString release]
```

So your tempString no longer exist outside the method, because nothing retain it.

But when you add NSlog inside [readString] with myString, NSLog will keep reference to the pointer (i don't know exactly how), but he actually does since he logs them.

Comment: It's the same effect if I use
        `printf("myString: %s", [myString UTF8String]);`
so it's nothing special with NSLog.

Comment: it's nothing with NSLog, but with ARC YES.

Comment: it's the same effect because printf("myString: %s", [myString UTF8String]), arc will make the pointer alive as long as adress of method [myString UTF8String] is required. The only way to know exactly what happen is to read the code generated from asm. What is sure is that without printf or NSlog, arc will nihil the pointer inside the scope of the function. When u use global function or global reference (not weak), arc will not nihil the pointer inside the scope of the function. That's why you still can have the weak pointer right after the method call